# Give an epsilon-delta proof to show that f ·g is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces, epsilon-delta

Let (M,d) be a metric space, let (V,||·||) be a real normed vector space, and let f : M →R and g : M → V be continuous. Give an epsilon-delta proof to show that f ·g is continuous, where · is scalar multiplication on V .

I am trying to define a delta for the norm of the the difference f·g to be less then epsilon. But here is where I stuck on. Could someone give a formal proof or provide any other possible way to show that? Many thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\begin{align}&|f(x)g(x) - f(x_0)g(x_0)| \\
=&\|f(x)g(x) - f(x_0) g(x) + f(x_0)g(x) - f(x_0)g(x_0)\|\\
\leq& |f(x)-f(x_0)|\cdot\|g(x)\| + |f(x_0)|\cdot\|g(x)-g(x_0)\|\\
\leq& M\cdot (|f(x)-f(x_0)| + \|g(x)-g(x_0)\|)\end{align}$$

for some value of $M$.

Now, picking $x_0$ close to $x$ will allow you to cause $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ to be small, and $\|g(x)-g(x_0)\|$ to also be small.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how do we get from the third line to the fourth line. Also, once we have the fourth line, how do we find the relation between delta and epsilon? I think we need to convert the above inequality into an inequality about d(x,xo) as we assumed d(x,x0) is less than delta.

Comment: @Y.X. Third to fourth is simple, you just need to find $M$ that is bigger than both $\|g(x)\|$ and $|f(x_0)|$. The relation between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ is what you still need to figure out. For example, do you know of any way in which you could be sure that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ will be small? Like, some restriction on $d(x,x_0)$?

Comment: @Y.X. My *hint* is precisely that, a **hint**. You still have to do some work to finish the job.